# Ability to tag friends in a facebook native share dialogue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using the Facebook iOS SDK 3.1 in my latest, and I'm using the native share dialogue from `FBNativeDialogue`.

[image]

It has a "friends" button in the corner, which I always throught was to tag friends (just like the location button tags the location), but I realised that this is privacy settings for the post.

Therefor, Im still confounded how you can tag friends in a post. Nothing seems to happend when i type @ followed by my friends names, is this not implemented yet ? And does anyone know of clever way to implement this ?

What the customer wants is the similar to the "Who are you with?" button as shown here:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just don't think this is possible, considering the current Facebook SDK (3.5.1) documentation -- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/#nativepostcontroller. It states:

> iOS 6 includes a native Share Sheet that lets users post status updates, photos, links, and locations to Facebook and includes support for setting the audience for the post and tagging the post with a location.

Even when you post something on Facebook from iOS' Notification Center, it only allows you to share the information mentioned above, without tagging friends.

Instead, you could use the Facebook views, as they do here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/show-friends/. But if you have to use the Native Dialogs, I can't see a way. If you get it to work, please let us know the solution.